# Testing Parse push notification with 2 iOS device, one always got "invalid token"

Tags: ios, parse-platform, push-notification

I'm testing Parse Push Notification with two iOS device, iPhone 6s and iPad Mini 3, same iOS version, same source code, on the iPhone the app (Parse source code example) works flawlessly but on the iPad I got always "invalid token" message and it never deliver the push notification.

Any ideas on what I should check?

I've deleted the app more than one time, turned off the connection but nothing changed.

Comment: I suppose you run the app on both using the same environment (i.e. both directly connected to your Mac, using "Run" in Xcode, which uses the development environment, or both via Test Flight, which uses the production environment)? If you have ever run the app on either device in both environments, checked that the token environment matches the environment that is used for sending (not sure how Parse handle that, though).

Comment: Yes, same environment :(

Answer (score 0):

Ok that was a problem around Provisioning Profile, I close the question, sorry.